# Can I delete something that is building and save the build progress for later?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a wizard tower building and I want to remove it so I have some space. If I add it later on, will it continue building in my storage?

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel the building being built, but the time resets.

Source: personal experience